# Concatenating embedded inputs to feed recurrent LSTM in keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to figure out how to feed a functional model to LSTM gates in keras. I've got a time series of tuples (int, float, float). The ints are not ordered and should go through and embedding layer. I then want the tuples (after embedding the int) to go through an LSTM layer.

I've started with

```html
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM

import keras

inputs = [(42, 0.5, 0.6), (36, 0.4, 0.7), (50, 0.2, 0.9)] # example. The real data is a sequence of millions of tuples

input_id = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='input_type') # id is within [0, 99]
embed_id = Embedding(output_dim=3, input_dim=20, input_length=1)(input_id)

input_v1 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='float', name='input_v1')
input_v2 = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='float', name='input_v2')

input_merged = keras.layers.concatenate([embed_id, input_v1, input_v2], axis=-1)

lstm = LSTM(40) # how do I tell it to use input_merged as input ?
```

The concatenate complains:
*ValueError: `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 1, 3), (None, 1), (None, 1)]*

This I'm pretty sure could be arrange with reshapes. But What I'm really wondering: Is this the right approach to feeding Keras time sequences of data needing some processing ?

I'm also unsure how to feed the LSTM gates the concatenated results. All the recurrent examples I could find use sequential models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The embedding layer will need that you have the entire sequence of integers, so it can compute correctly.

So, as a first step, I'd split the input data:

```
intInputs = np.array([el[0] for el in inputs])    
floatInputs = np.array([el[1],el[2]] for el in inputs)
    #this could be optimized creating empty numpy arrays first and doing only one loop to fill them
```

After that, we must understand that if we're giving the entire sequence to the embedding, we must also pass the entire sequence to the model. For that, I think it's best to reshape the inputs to have "one sample" of many time steps (unless you really have more than one sequence):

```
intInputs = intInputs.reshape((1,seqLength))   
floatInputs = floatInputs.reshape((1,seqLength,2))
```

Then we go to the model:

```
input_id=Input((seqLength,))
input_v =Input((seqLength,2))

embed_id = Embedding(output_dim=3,input_dim=20,input_length=seqLength)(input_id)
    #are you sure "input_dim" is 20? Normally you should have the total amount of existing Ids, and I suppose this should at least be the last id+1.
```

With this, the concatenation will have shapes (None,seqLength,3), (None,seqLength,2), and you will be able to concat in the last axis (the others are equal in length).

```
input_merged = Concatenate(axis=-1)([embed_id,input_v])
```

And the LSTM receives the input as any other layer:

```
lstm = LSTM(40)(input_merged)
```